# Lost Windows 7 boot entry after installing Grub customizer

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

The title says it all. I installed grub-customizer, made some changes to the GUI, and lost my Windows boot entries. I've tried running sudo update-grub, but it didn't detect Windows. How can I recover the boot option?

Comment: please make sure that the windows volume is mounted before running sudo update-grub. then it will pick up the windows partition.

Answer (score 2):

You should repair your windows installation with your Windows bootable DVD, using the [Repair your computer](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/win7-windows-7-mbr,10036.html) option, and after you finish with this one, you can download [Boot Repair CD](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/) iso image and burn it on a regular CD or put it on USB key via Unetbootin. I assume you still have the installation disc for WIN7?

Oh, useless to say that you should get rid of 'grub-customizer' as soon as you can.

Boot Repair CD comes in 2 versions, one is for 32bit OS and the other for 64bit OS. So if you installed **Win7 64bit** you'll be needing **boot-repair-disk-64bit.iso** image, and the 32bit iso image for Win7 32bit.

After you make sure that you can boot into Win7, you can place your new Boot Repair CD in tray or use the USB version and restart your computer. Allow the CD to load its system, and choose the **Recommended Repair** option once you are in the live session with Boot Repair CD.

After you restart your computer again and, hopefully, boot into Ubuntu you should run the **sudo update-grub** command so Ubuntu be able to list your Windows in the boot menu.

Comment: [That tutorial](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/win7-windows-7-mbr,10036.html) in the link I gave you is for repairing Win7 mbr. I hope you are using Win7 and not Win8.

Comment: I tried following the tutorial to no avail. After a while, I figured out that my Windows repair disk couldn't detect my HDD. Can I do this from Ubuntu?

Comment: Tried running boot repair. Results: http://pastebin.com/F3zsDQXE

Comment: Should I try using boot repair to restore the MBR?

Comment: Do you still have grub-customizer installed? Maybe it saved some sort of backups to be able to restore your grub to its default state. Otherwise, yes, use boot repair to fix the grub, but I won't promise you will be able to boot into Windows. Those 'locked' messages that are showing in your config file may be the result of using grub-customizer in a hurry. You should try to restore any hidden entry and maybe there is an option in grub-customizer menu to restore grub to the default settings. Never used it so I can't tell you much about it but it looks like a dangerous piece of... software.

Comment: Forgot to tell you that if you get lucky with 'Recommended Option' in Boot Repair CD, you need to run **sudo update-grub** after reboot and login to Ubuntu. This way, Ubuntu will eventually detect Windows, and you are on the right track. If win7 won't boot after restart, you can try using Win7 DVD again to fix the mbr. And, of course, Boot Repair CD again...

Answer (score 2):

IRST metadata from Windows was causing conflicts after grub settings were updated. I followed the steps in [this article](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1758396) to remove it. After that, I ran update-grub and allowed Windows to run chkdsk. All is well, and IRST is reenabled.